# Aggregation in Meteor. Mongo db

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I have this data in my mongo db:

```
{ "_id" : "uhNTGacKPbnykv99S", "text" : "Task1", "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-03-20T10:29:59.669Z"), "owner" : "RE349TrQXoBm32mbr", "username" : "AngryRoot", "private" : false, "checked" : false }
{ "_id" : "PsX7ZvyDoD26Kr78X", "text" : "Task2", "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-03-20T10:30:01.598Z"), "owner" : "RE349TrQXoBm32mbr", "username" : "AngryRoot", "private" : false, "checked" : false }
{ "_id" : "mXpPWJ93GjugNCyME", "text" : "Task3", "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-03-20T10:30:15.899Z"), "owner" : "FbcQxF9q5a3t3LG9i", "username" : "CandyOgre", "private" : false, "checked" : false }
{ "_id" : "WciNvRpZNAeiHNGhz", "text" : "Task4", "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-03-20T10:30:18.785Z"), "owner" : "FbcQxF9q5a3t3LG9i", "username" : "CandyOgre", "private" : false, "checked" : false }
```

Get it from mongo console with `db.tasks.find()`.

I want to return collection, where tasks from current owner will come first.

For example. If I logged in as AngryRoot, I want to show AngryRoot`s tasks first, and then other tasks from other users. I think I need to use aggregation. Installed this package: [meteorhacks:aggregate](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate).

All my tries failed, help me, if you can.
And a file where i need to aggregate: [enter link description here](https://github.com/CandyOgre/Meteorized-ToDo-List/blob/master/client/templates/simple-todos.js#L11) (On 11 raw).

Thank you for spending time for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have command over meteor, but you can definitely do this using aggregation framework by stitching couple of stages in aggregation pipeline.

```
db.tasks.aggregate([
    // project a field showing if current user is owner
    {$project: 
      {text:1, createdAt:1, owner:1, username:1, private:1, checked:1, current: 
        {$eq: ["$username", "AngryRoot"]}
      }
    },
    // Sort stage: Brings documents on top with current = true
    {$sort: 
      {current:-1}
    },
    // Optional!. Remove field name 'current' induced in first stage
    {$project:
      {text:1, createdAt:1, owner:1, username:1, private:1, checked:1}
    } 
])
```

This should print records (assuming `AngryRoot` is current user)

```
{ 
    "_id" : "uhNTGacKPbnykv99S", 
    "text" : "Task1", 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-03-20T10:29:59.669+0000"), 
    "owner" : "RE349TrQXoBm32mbr", 
    "username" : "AngryRoot", 
    "private" : false, 
    "checked" : false
}
{ 
    "_id" : "PsX7ZvyDoD26Kr78X", 
    "text" : "Task2", 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-03-20T10:30:01.598+0000"), 
    "owner" : "RE349TrQXoBm32mbr", 
    "username" : "AngryRoot", 
    "private" : false, 
    "checked" : false
}
{ 
    "_id" : "mXpPWJ93GjugNCyME", 
    "text" : "Task3", 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-03-20T10:30:15.899+0000"), 
    "owner" : "FbcQxF9q5a3t3LG9i", 
    "username" : "CandyOgre", 
    "private" : false, 
    "checked" : false
}
{ 
    "_id" : "WciNvRpZNAeiHNGhz", 
    "text" : "Task4", 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-03-20T10:30:18.785+0000"), 
    "owner" : "FbcQxF9q5a3t3LG9i", 
    "username" : "CandyOgre", 
    "private" : false, 
    "checked" : false
}
```

Comment: But how it better to organize in meteor? I can use meteorhacks:aggregate package, but I can use it only on server. Should I create new method for this or how ?

Comment: @МаксимРоманюк unfortunately I don't know anything about meteor so can't suggest anything. But I guess having a separate method to wrap aggregate is not a bad idea.